# How Do I Add the Results of a Looped Input File?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, ifstream

I'm a beginner at C++ and created an input file with calculated call rates. I was able to calculate the cost of each call individually; however, I'm not sure how to...

1. Take the results of each call and total them up together.
2. Accurately calculate the costs of calls that span from day to nighttime/weekday to weekend.

This is what I have so far. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

**Call_History.txt**

```
(Day/Time/Duration/Cost)

Mo 1330 16 $6.40

Mo 815  35 $14.00

Tu 750  20 $3.00

We 1745 30 $12.00

Th 800  45 $18.00

Su 2350 30 $4.50
```

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const double DAYTIME = 0.40;
const double NIGHT = 0.25;
const double WEEKEND = 0.15;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Call_History.txt");

    string day;
    int time;
    int duration;
    int dayOfWeek;
    double cost;
    double total;

    // Set the numeric output formatting.
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Day Time Duration Cost\n" << endl;

    while (fin >> day >> time >> duration)
    {
        if (day == "Mo")
        {
            dayOfWeek = 1;
        }
        else if (day == "Tu")
        {
            dayOfWeek = 2;
        }
        else if (day == "We")
        {
            dayOfWeek = 3;
        }
        else if (day == "Th")
        {
            dayOfWeek = 4;
        }
        else if (day == "Fr")
        {
            dayOfWeek = 5;
        }
        else if (day == "Sa")
        {
            dayOfWeek = 6;
        }
        else if (day == "Su")
        {
            dayOfWeek = 7;
        }

        // Determine cost of call based on rate schedule.
        if ((time >= 800) && (time <= 1800) && (dayOfWeek <= 5))
        {
            cost = duration * DAYTIME;
        }
        else if ((time < 800) && (time > 1800) && (dayOfWeek <= 5))
        {
            cost = duration * NIGHT;
        }
        else
        {
            cost = duration * WEEKEND;
        }
        cout << day << " " << time << " " << duration << " $" << cost << endl;

    }

    cout << "\nTotal $" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: you have four input or five tokens per line (`Mo 1330 16 $6.40`) and three tokens read(`fin >> day >> time >> duration`). Reading the price could give you fits, so I'd get that figured out before going too much further and having to do a massive re-write to fit it in.

Comment: also off topic: you can change your dayOfWeek variable into an isWeekday variable, thus reducing your if statements from 7 to 2. i.e. if day == "Mo" | "Tu"...

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a summation variable, such as `double sum = 0.0;`
2. After you read a `cost` from an input line, add it to the sum:  `sum += cost;`
3. When you print the total, print the sum: `cout << "\nTotal $" << sum << endl;`.

Answer (score 0):

Call history includes price, so the program you've listed wouldn't work after the first line. However, if you modify `Call_History.txt` like this, it would work

```
Mo 1330 16

Mo 815  35

Tu 750  20

We 1745 30

Th 800  45

Su 2350 30
```

Besides a simple recommendation to sum up all the cost you get in the `total` variable, you should also consider refactoring your program into simple functions, for example, `dayOfWeek` and cost factor calculations just beg to be placed in separate functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

//function to wrap the day lookup
int getDayOfWeek(string const &day) {
    //create a constant map to make lookup more convenient
    static const map<string, int> dayOfWeek = { { "Mo", 1 },{ "Tu", 2 },{ "We", 3 },{ "Th", 4 },{ "Fr", 5 },{ "Sa", 6 },{ "Su", 7 } };
    auto dayIterator = dayOfWeek.find(day);
    if (dayIterator == dayOfWeek.cend()) {
        //Couldn't find a match for a specified day
        return 0;
    }
    return dayIterator->second;
}

double getCostMultiplier(int time, int dayOfWeek) {
    const double DAYTIME = 0.40;
    const double NIGHT = 0.25;
    const double WEEKEND = 0.15;

    //evaluate day of week to make comparisons simplier and easier to read
    if (dayOfWeek > 5) {
        return WEEKEND;
    }
    else if ((time >= 800) && (time <= 1800))
    {
        return DAYTIME;
    }
    else
    {
        return NIGHT;
    }

    //default case so that if the conditions would change and there would be other cases this function would return something meaningful
    return WEEKEND;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Call_History.txt");

    string day;
    int time = 0;
    int duration = 0;
    int dayOfWeek = 0;
    double cost = 0;
    double total = 0;

    // Set the numeric output formatting.
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Day Time Duration Cost\n" << endl;

    while (fin >> day >> time >> duration)
    {
        dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(day);
        cost = duration * getCostMultiplier(time, dayOfWeek);
        cout << day << " " << time << " " << duration << " $" << cost << endl;

        //add cost to total
        total += cost;
    }

    cout << "\nTotal $" << total << endl;

    return 0;
}
```